# How can I resolve "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got Number." for JSON payloads in Power Automate?

Tags: json, api, power-automate

I'm getting an error in a sample JSON payload using the `Parse JSON` function in a Power Automate flow:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got Number.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "issues[0].fields.customfield_18478",
    "value": 1,
    "schemaId": "#/properties/issues/items/properties/fields/properties/customfield_18478",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
}
```

The above is a sample error I have been getting for custom fields in JIRA. Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: Please post all the fields that fail in your code.

Comment: @philoez98  all the custom fields are failing like customfield_18479,customfield_18485,customfield_18486 etc

Comment: Encountered same issue with logic apps Parse JSON Data Operations; added ["integer", "number"] to items causing 'Invalid type' error as per Arun and solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have to define the schema for both `integer` and `number`. This should solve the issue.

```
"customfield_18478": {

"type": ["integer", "number"]

},
```

[Reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Parsing-JSON-Response-error-quot-message-quot-quot-Invalid-type/m-p/301536/highlight/true#M31930)

Comment: Thanks for that: I added this schema for an error I have occurred on my code and its works now.

"properties": {
          "overall_satisfaction": {"type": ["double", "number"]},
    }